# How to convert files from Catia v5 into Babylon.js format?

Tags: babylonjs, catia

I have a supplier using WebGL to create a 3D application for me. He requested the data in Babylon.js format.  However, I only have the data in Catia v5 format.  Which version should I provide the data in to allow for a conversion to Babylon? And, how could I convert from Catia v5 to Babylon.js?

Comment: Added the tag WebGL, inserted the main question into the body, and fixed minor grammatical issues.

Comment: Removed the WebGL tag. This is not a WebGL question. WebGL as no knowledge of models. That responsibility is to libraries that may or may not use WebGL

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct convertor from CATIA V5 or CATIA V6 (no mater the release) to Babylon.js. What you can do is to ask your supplier if he can use a neutral format like igs or stp, both CATIA versions can export those formats.